# /broadcasting/auth route does not work to respond to channel authorization requests

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I am using [Pusher](https://pusher.com/) to Make real-time laravel notifications.

Laravel by default registered `/broadcasting/auth` route to handle authorization requests via `Broadcast::routes();` included in `BroadcastServiceProvider`.

And in initialization of Pusher, there is a `authEndpoint` option that can use for Setting the Channel Authentication endpoint like this:

```
var pusher  = new Pusher("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", {
                authEndpoint: '/broadcasting/auth',
                auth: {
                    headers: {
                        'X-CSRF-Token': '{{ csrf_token() }}'
                    }
                }
            });
```

As you can see I set it to `/broadcasting/auth` that is declared by laravel.

But when Pusher send a POST request to it , laravel throws a 403 error and redirect to a 403 error page that I  created before.

what is Problem and How can I solve that ?

Comment: can you remove 403 error page to get the error stack ?

Comment: ohhh, my problem was beacause I used a condition in `Broadcast::channel('App.User.*', function ($user, $userId) {` that always return false and therefore redirect users to 403 error page that I has created for unauthorized users. thanks @jaysingkar for your idea.

Comment: problem solved ? is it working ?

Comment: Yes, my Problem is solved. in fact it worked but beacause `Broadcast::channel('App.User.*'` returned false , laravel redirected throws and 403 error.